# How to integrate the square of a gradient over a volume

Tags: vector-analysis

I've been reviewing a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys3035) on modeling starling flocks and I am struggling to follow a jump in the math. They have the following:

(1) $H = \frac{J}{2}\sum_\limits{\langle ij\rangle} (\phi_i-\phi_j)^2 = \frac{1}{2}a^2J\int\frac{d^3x}{a^3}[\nabla \phi (x,t)]^2$

(2) $\frac{\partial \phi}{\ t} = -\frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi}=a^2J\nabla^2\phi$

where $J$ is a constant, $a$ is the average  nearest-neighbor distance, and $\phi_i$ is the angle between the direction of motion of bird $i$ and the flock

What is not clear to me is how the following happens:

$-\frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi} = -\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi} \left(\frac{1}{2}a^2J\int\frac{d^3x}{a^3}[\nabla \phi (x,t)]^2\right)\to a^2J\nabla^2\phi$

I thought maybe they were they were using vector properties

$\int [\nabla \phi]^2 d^3x = \int \nabla \cdot(\phi\nabla\phi)d^3x-\int \phi \nabla^2\phi d^3x$

where by the divergence theorem $\int \nabla \cdot(\phi\nabla\phi)d^3x = \int\phi\nabla\phi n dS\to0$ as the integration is all over space so the surface S goes to infinity. This process would get rid of the negative sign but then applying the $\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi}$, I think it would become

$-\frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi} =\frac{1}{2}a^2J\int\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta \phi}\left[\phi\nabla^2 \phi\right]\right)\frac{d^3x}{a^3}=\frac{1}{2}a^2J\int\left(\nabla^2 \phi +\phi\nabla^2(1)\right)\frac{d^3x}{a^3}=\frac{1}{2}a^2J\int\nabla^2 \phi \frac{d^3x}{a^3}$

but that doesn't seem to be right, as then the integral of the Laplacian would just give you back the Laplacian. I've been out of school for over a decade, so I'm assuming there is basic vector calculus that I don't remember that would fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured out most of it. Really I needed to be more focused on the the variance $\frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi}$. I believe they're using the functional derivative ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative)):

Given:

$H[\phi] = \int \frac{f(x,\nabla \phi (x))}{a^3} d^3x$

then

$\int \frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)}\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3} d^3x =\left[\frac{d}{d\epsilon} \int \frac{f(x,\nabla \phi(x) +\epsilon\nabla\rho(x))}{a^3}d^3x\right]_{\epsilon=0} $

$\int \frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)}\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3} d^3x =\left[ \int \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\frac{(\nabla \phi(x) +\epsilon\nabla\rho(x))^2}{a^3}d^3x\right]_{\epsilon=0} $

$\int \frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)}\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3} d^3x =\left[ \int \frac{2(\nabla \phi(x) +\epsilon\nabla\rho(x))\nabla\rho(x)}{a^3}d^3x\right]_{\epsilon=0} $

$\int \frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)}\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3} d^3x = \int \frac{2\nabla \phi(x)\nabla\rho(x)}{a^3}d^3x $

from vector properties and the divergence theorem

$\int \frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)}\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3} d^3x =\int \frac{-2\nabla^2 \phi(x)\rho(x)}{a^3}d^3x $

$\int \frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)}\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3} d^3x =\int -2\nabla^2 \phi(x)\frac{\rho(x)}{a^3}d^3x $

so then

$\frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)} =-2\nabla^2 \phi(x) $

which combined with the original $H = \frac{a^2J}{2}\int d^3x (\nabla\phi)^2$ gives

$-\frac{\delta H}{\delta \phi(x)} =a^2J\nabla^2 \phi(x) $

Though it seems a bit hand-wavy how they drop the $a^3$ and not the other constants.